# Basic usage commands of Percona Server?

Tags: mysql, database, percona

Im trying to use Percona Server with XtraDB with Drupal

But the documentation not describe the basic usage like how to login to the 
CLI (MySQL use`mysql -u root -p`), how to create database, etc

Connecting Drupal with MariaDB is very easy because all the commands are same. How about Percona Server?

Answer (score 2):

The CLI commands are all the same. In fact, everything is the same. Percona is MySQL with some internal tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

As taken from the first line of the [Percona Server website](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/):

*Percona Server with XtraDB is a **backwards-compatible** replacement for MySQL that is much faster and more scalable...*

It's backwards-compatible, so you just use it like you use any installation of mysql. Same commands, same flags, etc. I'd get a grip of the basics of a standard mysql setup before heading off into the land of performance-based forks.